# Laravel 5.8 cannot generate api_token when new user register

Tags: laravel, api

I am playing around with Laravel Authentication.

On a freshly created Laravel app with Composer, I followed literally the instructions until this point (included)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#generating-tokens

When I register a new user, however, the api_token field is NULL.

What else do I need to do in order to start generating the api token when a user registers??

Create method in RegisterController:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'api_token' => Str::random(60),
    ]);
}
```

Migration (I called it Token) updating the users table:

```
class Token extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('api_token', 80)->after('password')
            ->unique()
            ->nullable()
            ->default(null);
        });
    }
```

App\User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your user model? My guess is api_token is not part of your `protected $fillables`.

Comment: sure. Here you go in the edits. The User model is untouched from the initial scaffolding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your user model add 'api_token' to your fillables

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 
    'email', 
    'password', 
    'api_token'
];
```

Comment: working. What about the "remember_token" field? should I also include in the fillable?

Comment: I don't think you have to add that as laravel deals with it that already. Any field you add after the initial setup that you want to modify should be added to the models `$fillble` property.

Comment: @RicardoVigatti it should be but Taylor enjoys closing PRs

Answer (score 1):

After creating migration , run  [**the migrate Artisan**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#running-migrations) command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

If you are using the [**Homestead virtual machine**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead), you should run this command from within your virtual machine:

```
php artisan migrate --force
```